# CSS psuedo-class first-line overrides first-letter

Tags: css, fonts, overriding

My problem is this, that I want to style the first line and first letter of every paragraph but the first-line attributes move on to the first-letter attributes even if I re-declare them in the declaration of first-letter.

This is how the code looks:

```
p:first-line {
 font-variant:small-caps;
}
p:first-letter {
 font:none;
 font-variant:none !important;
 font-family: firstLetterFont !important;
 font-size:200%;
 font-weight:bold;
}
```

The problem is that my custom font (firstLetterFont) is not being used for the first-letter, instead the default Times New Roman is used. I placed !important tags but to no avail.

Anyone have any method of overriding the attributes of first-line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, sorry, rookie mistake.

Seems there is no such thing as "none" for font-variant, is should be set to "normal".

My bad.